# How to define function that returns html in asp.net core

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Basically I need something like old asp.net

```
@helper MakeNote(string content) {
    <p><strong>Note</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; @content    </p>
}
```

or JSX

```
MakeNote(note) {
   return (<div>Note {note}</div>);
}
```

A partial view is not an option. I am happy with either a function returning an IHtmlString, or a function writing to the underlying writer.

It also needs to support Razor Syntax (not just string concatenation) inside the function.

Comment: You can create a tag helper to return your custom HTML markup. BTW, your **OR JSX** part makes this question very broad (at least for me)

Comment: This is just example of what I need from another language, I do not see how does it make question broad.

Comment: I just gave 2 examples of what I need and tag helper is nowhere close.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since **ASP.NET Core 3.0**, we can declare **Local Functions** containing markup to serve as templating methods, inside *Razor Code Blocks*:

```
@{
    void RenderName(string name)
    {
        <p>Name: <strong>@name</strong></p>
    }

    RenderName("Mahatma Gandhi");
    RenderName("Martin Luther King, Jr.");
}
```

Which renders the following HTML Code:

```
<p>Name: <strong>Mahatma Gandhi</strong></p>
<p>Name: <strong>Martin Luther King, Jr.</strong></p>
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#razor-code-blocks

---

(just for sake of completion) In **ASP.NET Core 2.0** we can use **Templated Razor delegates**, which combined with the `<text></text>` razor tag (Explicit Delimited Transition), allow us to make something similar to an old day's ASP.NET MVC `@helper` tag:

```
@{
    Func<string, object> RenderName = @<text>
        <p>
            Name: <strong>@item</strong>
        </p>;
    </text>;
}

<div>
    @RenderName("Victor")
</div>
```

Which renders the following HTML Code:

```
<div>
    <p>
        Name: <strong>Victor</strong>
    </p>
</div>
```

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.0#templated-razor-delegates

Documentation `<text></text>`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.0#razor-code-blocks

Comment: If your function return void than in html markup call function inside braces. Like this: @{ RenderName("Victor"); }

Answer (score 19):

You might be looking for [`@functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.1#section-5) that use [`Html.Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.raw?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_IHtmlHelper_Raw_System_Object_).

Here is an example that shows two function styles. The first uses a traditional block body, the second uses an expression-body.

Both of them have the `$@` prefix on the string.

- The `$` enables `{interpoloation}` in the string.
- The `@` makes a verbatim string, which can span multiple lines.

The third way is somewhat of a hack that lets us parse Razor inside the function. It's as close as we seem to be able to get to the original `@helper` syntax.

**SomeRazorFile.cshtml**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html

@functions 
{
    IHtmlContent MakeNote(string content) 
    {
        return Html.Raw($@"
            <p>
                <strong>Note</strong> {content}
            </p>
        ");
    }

    // an alternative that uses method shorthand
    IHtmlContent MakeNoteToo(string content) => Html.Raw($@"
        <p>
            <strong>Note</strong> {content}
        </p>
    ");
}

@{
    // an alternative that parses razor
    Func<string, IHtmlContent> MakeNoteThree = 
        @<p>
            <strong>Note</strong> {@item}
        </p>;
}

<div>
    @MakeNote("Foo")
    @MakeNoteToo("Bar")
    @MakeNoteThree("Baz")
</div>
```

Edit: Added an example that parses Razor. See https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/715 for details.

Comment: It kind-of works, but I want to use Razor inside that function, not string concatenation.

Comment: @user2029276 Good to know. I added an example that uses Razor inside the function. Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: I saw it already on github, but I think it is kind of hack, rather than official solution. Syntax is kinda weird, and argument isn't named. Can You add more arguments?

Comment: Yes. You can add more arguments. The method of doing that is more of a hack though; it involves passing a tuple to the func.

Comment: Not to worry. It's indeed unfortunate that Core does not support the `@helper` style from the full framework.

Comment: Alternative for latest .net core?

Comment: For a workaround to the limitation of the parameters, you can use Tuples. i.e. `Func<(string name, int value), IHtmlContent> CreateInput = @<input name="@item.name" value="@item.value" />`

Answer (score 3):

I would like to provide an overview answer to simplify this post.

The closest approach to the question is **@Vitox's answer**, but lacks how to call the method in place:

```
@{
    void MakeNote(string content)
    {
        <p><strong>Note</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; @content    </p>
    }
}
```

This is good for helpers with a lot of C# code and is called like this:

```
<div>
  <p>Today is a great day for programming.</p>
  @{MakeNote("Have a nice day!");}
</div>
```

In case you don't like the `@{Method(params);}` construct, I suggest **@Shaun Luttin's answer**:

```
Func<string, IHtmlContent> MakeNote = 
    @<p><strong>Note</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp; @item    </p>;
}
```

This is good for HTML oriented helpers and is called like this:

```
<div>
  <p>Today is a great day for programming.</p>
  @MakeNote("Have a nice day!")
</div>
```

I don't know why Shaun wrote `{@item}` in his code, but I did notice that sometimes VS 2022 requires cleaning up the project to compile such code.

Here is an **extended example** with this second approach:

```
Func<ValueTuple<int, string>, IHtmlContent> SomeMethod =
@<p>
    @{int x = item.Item1 + 2;}
    <strong>Note</strong> @(item.Item2 + x)
</p>;
```

When calling like this `@SomeMethod((5, "Have a good day!"))` the following output is displayed:

```
<p>
    <strong>Note</strong> Have a good day!7
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having to convert old Helpers to something as close as possible in .net 5 and I've had good luck with this so far. Not saying it's best, but it works.

Old Helper now as a function...

```
public static string Helper1(string name) {
   string html = null;
   html += "<p>Hi, my name is <strong>@name</strong></p>";
   html += "<p>It's nice to meet you!</p>";
   return html;
}
```

Include the reference and call on any Page...

```
<div>
   @Html.Raw(Helper1("Josh"))
</div>
```