# Display content twice on page but define content only once

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a block of markup I use to link to the next and previous pages. I would like this markup to appear both before and after a table of data.

Is there a way to define this markup only once but show it twice, *without using a partial view*?

I seem to remember MVC having some sort of page subroutine that creates markup and could be called from anywhere in the page. But I don't recall the syntax for this and can find it anywhere online.

Comment: A better solution for this scenario is a custom tag helper: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-tag-helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `@helper`, but it's [not supported in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#razor-reserved-keywords) for reasons explained [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/281).

Right at the end of [this discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5110#issuecomment-474951631), there's a comment that they've added support for HTML code in `@functions` blocks. There's an example there too. But that [commit](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore-Tooling/commit/5ffd84e56dd3d21b48d55feea5bc1493d0293fd1) was just on March 14, 2019, so it may not have made it to any released version yet. (maybe when ASP.NET Core 3 is released?)

But if that's not available, you could just use a function in [`@functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-2.2#functions) that returns a string of HTML using `Html.Raw()`, like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52107634/1202807).

Comment: That looks like it, thanks, but it doesn't appear to be supported in Razor Pages. IntelliSense tells me *The name 'helper' does not exist in the current context.*

Comment: Make sure you're not putting it inside a `@section` or anything else. It has to be at the root level of the cshtml page.

Comment: I just tried it in an MVC 5 project targetting .NET 4.7 and it works. Maybe your project is different somehow.

Comment: Yes, it is different. You're using Razor syntax in MVC. I'm using Razor Pages. Looks like this feature was pulled from  Razor Pages.

Comment: Oh, you're using ASP.NET Core? Your tags threw me off.