# Razor template/component solution that supports child Razor markup

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

Is there a template/component solution in ASP.NET Core Razor, **that supports inner Razor markup**?

Here's a use case:

**1. Say I have some repetitive markup** for example "a `div` with nice borders, shadows and two buttons at the bottom"

**2. Obviously this markup has a common "header" and a "footer"** in the HTML code

**3. I need to pass arbitrary Razor markup to insert between header and footer.** Not just a model object - but some actual markup that will be rendered between header and footer. I can't use `foreach` because this markup is different every time - it can be text-content, a form, an image, or some complicated Razor-rendered stuff.

### Basically I'm looking for a "Surround this Razor with more Razor" templating solution

Something like:

```
@{
    //this function renders my beautiful box
    Func<dynamic, IHtmlContent> myFunction = @<div class="relative flex flex-col rounded-2xl border border-gray-200 bg-white p-8 shadow-sm">
        @item
    </div>;
}

<!-- and then I call it passing some Razor as input -->
@myFunction(
    <ul>
        <li>@SomeRazorMethod()</li>
    </ul>

);
```

Something like a `Layout` - but the one I can use multiple times on the same page.

Is there anything like that? This is a pretty common componentizing tool - "wrap my markup with other markup" - that is present in other templating engines (React, Vue, etc), but apparently not in Razor.

Just to be clear: I'm looking for a *Razor-based solution*, not a C#-based one. So that my header-footer markup stays in *markup* files (.cshtml), not in C# files that will have hard-coded HTML magic strings.

Comment: Partial view supports child razor content. Have you tried it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @Shah nope, I cannot pass razor markup from parent page to be rendered in a partial view

Comment: You don't need to pass markup from parent page in partial view. You can pass the parent page model to partial view and then just include it in parent cshtml like `@await Html.PartialAsync("_PartialName", customerData)`

Comment: @Shah that was not the question. I need a reusable control with common header/footer that I can pass arbitrary Razor to.

Comment: Ah its more clear now. Seems you need to pass razor syntax string to partial view. If that's the case, I don't think so mvc supports that. I feel it will be much better to pass values to partial view instead of razor string. It will be clean approach and with razor string there is very high chance of syntax/runtime errors.

Comment: @Shah forget about "partial", I just need a template to wrap Razor code snippet into a repetitive template

Comment: added answer based on your case. Hope that helps.

Comment: Many solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52104286/9971404).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shah's answer got me one step closer to a solution, however, it seems like the the actual question I'm trying to solve is "can I pass Razor markup as an input parameter".

Turns out you can, you just have to put `@` in front of it:

```
@{
    void MyFunc(Func<object, IHtmlContent> template)
    {
        <div>@template(null)</div>
    }
}


@{ MyFunc(@<div>The ID is: @Model.Id</div>); }
<!-- mind the '@' before the 'div' -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, this might help.

```
@functions {
    public static IHtmlContent MyBox(dynamic item, Func<dynamic, IHtmlContent> template)
    {
        var html = new HtmlContentBuilder();

        html.AppendHtml("<div class='bestcss'>");
        html.AppendHtml(template(item));
        html.AppendHtml("</div>");

        return html;
    }
}

@MyBox(null, @<div class='innercss'>@(10 == 12 ? "MyTest Equals" : "No Equal") hello</div>)
```

And if you like to pass modeldata, it will be:

```
@MyBox(customerdata, @<div class='innercss'>@(10 == 12 ? "MyTest Equals" : "No Equal") hello @item.FirstName</div>)
```

I have used some arbitrary if condition for testing.

Comment: Any hints on how the @item variable is accessible in the specified template? This seems like magic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Partial Pages](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/partial-pages) or Views which are `Razor` files containing snippets of `HTML` and server-side code to be included in any number of pages or layouts.

> Just like standard `Razor` pages, partial pages support the `@model`
> directive specifying the type for the partial's data model. All of the
> rendering methods have overloaded versions that take a model to be
> consumed in the partial.

Comment: Nope, you cannot pass arbitrary Razor content to a partial. Partials do not support child Razor content.

Comment: I tried rephrasing the question the best I could, may be that helps